Find and Replace Content Controls in Microsoft Word
Is it possible to use the find and replace module to find instances of content controls within a Microsoft Word document?

No, however, you could likely use vba (a macro). What, specifically are you trying to replace content controls with?

I wanted to see if it was possible to find a content control that validated a specific Regex and then replace the values with something specific. So I am guessing that we can have it work the same way as a Find and Replace Module, but instead of the module it is a input box for what value it should be replaced with?
